# How to write image data and GPS metadata to saved photos album using swift?

Tags: swift, alassetslibrary, ios8.1

I am trying to add GPS metadata to images I take using a custom camera application.  My camera app takes images as expected and there are lots of apple specific metadata values included in each picture I take.  However I can't seem to add GPS data.  What am I a doing wrong?  Thanks ahead.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

  var output : AVCaptureStillImageOutput!
  var locationManager : CLLocationManager()

  override func viewDidLoad()
    createCamera()
    initLocationManager()

    super.viewDidLoad()
  }

  func createCamera(){
  //create camera code.  works fine
  }

  func takePhoto(){
    self.output.captureStillImageAsynchronousFromConnection(self.connection){
      buffer, error in
      if let error = error{
        println("Error: \(error)")
      }
      else{
        var imageData = AVCaptureStillImageOutput.jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation(buffer)
        var metadata = self.getImageMetaData()
        var library = ALAssestsLibrary()
        library.writeImageDataToSavedPhotosAlbum(imageData, metadata, completionBlock: {
          (assetURL: NSURL!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

          })
       }
     }
  }

  func getImageMetadata() -> NSMutableDictionary{

    var locDict = NSMutableDictioary()
    locDict.setObject(self.locationManager.location.timestamp, forKey: "KCGImagePrropertyGPSTimeStamp")
    locDict.setObject("N", forKey: kCGImagePropertyGPSLatitudeRef")
    locDict.setObject(self.locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude, forKey: "kCGImagePropertyGPSLatitude")
    locDict.setObject("W", forKey: "kCGImagePropertyGPSLongitudeRef")
    locDict.setObject(self.locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude, forKey: "kCGImagePropertyGPSLongitude")

    return locDict
    //this returns the correct coordinates
    //NOTE: I hard coded the Ref values for brevity.
  }
}
```

NOTE: I am using [ExifTool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) to view the metadata.

Comment: Were you able to do it?